# Sorting with custom query data in paginator sort CakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting, cakephp

My controller query is as below :

```
$built_arr = $this->User->query("SELECT u1.id,
                                 CASE WHEN u1.role = 'CW' THEN u2.agency_name
                                 WHEN u3.role = 'EU' THEN u2.agency_name ELSE u1.agency_name END AS agency
                                 FROM users u1 LEFT JOIN users u2 ON (u1.parent = u2.id AND u2.role = 'A')
                                 LEFT JOIN users u3 ON (u1.id = u3.parent AND u1.role = 'CW') 
                                 LEFT JOIN users u4 ON (u1.parent = u4.id AND u4.role = 'A') 
                                 WHERE u1.role = 'A' OR u1.role = 'CW'
                                 GROUP BY u1.id");
```

And My code of array from this query is as below :

```
if (isset($built_arr) && !empty($built_arr)) {
        foreach ($built_arr AS $key => $value) {
            if (isset($value[0]['agency']) && !empty($value[0]['agency'])) {
                $agency_arr[$value['u1']['id']] = $value[0]['agency'];
            }
        }
}
```

Now I have set this data to view like as below :

```
$this->set('agency_arr', $agency_arr);
```

Now this Array (agency_arr), I have used as data of columns of a table in view page.
Now I want to sort that column with this array data.
My view code as below :

```
<th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('?', __("Agency Name"), array('escape' => false)); ?></th>
```

Advice for the "?" sign.
What I have to write instead of "?", So I can sort with my array data.
My other column's data come from the paginate query so those are working fine.
I need this extra query for extra column, so need to sort by that column.

Comment: If you user query, you are on your own. To paginate a bespoke query - either make the equivalent find call, or handle pagination yourself. Please tag your question with the version of CakePHP you are using.

Answer (score 0):

To the sort question:

Cake\View\Helper\PaginatorHelper::sort($key, $title = null, $options =[])
    Parameters:

```
    $key (string) – The name of the column that the recordset should be sorted.
    $title (string) – Title for the link. If $title is null $key will be used for the title and will be generated by inflection.
    $options (array) – Options for sorting link.
```

So i guess this is what you want: $paginator->sort('agency_name', 'Agency Name', array('escape' => false));

I would suggest to set up associations properly if you didnt already and use a find call with contains.
Since there are parents i guess its a HasAndBelongsToMany relation. (Children have multiple parents and parents multiple children)

```
CREATE TABLE `users` ( 
user_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
role varchar(255), 
);

CREATE TABLE `childrens_parents` ( 
childrens_parents_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
parent_id int, 
children_id int, 
FOREIGN KEY (u1_id) REFERENCES users(user_id), 
FOREIGN KEY (u2_id) REFERENCES users(user_id) 
);
```

In your Model/UsersTable set up the association properly like described in
the cakephp book
(dont forget targetforeignkey+foreignkey)

Now you can do something like this:

```
$query = $this->Users->find()->where(['role'=>'A'])->orWhere(['role'=>'CW'])->contain([
    'Children' => function ($q) {
       return $q
            ->where(['Role =' => 'CW']);
    }
])->contain([
    'Parents' => function ($q) {
       return $q
            ->where(['Role =' => 'A']);
    }
])->group('user_id');
```

Now you can paginate over the resultset accessing all fields of the objects.

```
foreach($query as $row) {
    debug($row);//see how nicely the resultarray is looking
    echo($row->Parents[0]->user-id);// access  related Entities
}
```

If its not HABTM but hasMany or some other type you can adapt it easily.
And I strongly recommend on holding in cake conventions !

Ressources (I recommend on reading the whole articles for proper cakephp work):
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html